# Site broke after installing new theme

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My web store broke after installing a new theme, but the error persists after changing the theme back to default.

This is the error displayed when visiting the site:

```
Notice: Undefined index: catalog.topnav  in /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 460

#0 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(460): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/havhokere...', 460, Array)
#1 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
#2 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
#3 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#11 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#12 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/havhokeren/public_html/magento/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Site: www.havhokeren.dk/magento Magento version 1.9.1.1
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add catalog.topnav block to the topnav reference.Layout file have issue in topnav references which create conflict with the core file.
you should change the reference according to the core file. It will help you.
And for prevent error on site please disable the developer mode.

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I disable developer mode in 1.9? Can't seem to find anything

Comment: please comment these three lines in your index.php
/*Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);*/

Comment: That worked, thank you. The error is still there, but not displayed.